# Join attributes from multiple polygons to an overlaying polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, fields-attributes

I have a polygon-shapefile, containing 562 single features (feeding -layer). I want to add their attributes to an overlapping polygon-layer (bear_buffer -layer), containing 1330 features. The bear-buffer features are overlapping in most cases, so I decided to use the intersect-tool for both layers, because I also need the exact area-sizes of the "feeding"-features inside the single "bear_buffer"-features (always total). This resulted in about 7,030,000 single features.

feeding -layer
[image: feeding -layer]
bear_buffer -layer
[image: bear_buffer -layer]
both layers
[image: both layers]

Now I want to add several attributes of the "feeding"-layer to the "bear_buffer"-layer, so I get for every "bear_buffer"-feature the attributes of the "feeding"-layer. The following 2 pictures will give an example of the 2-input-tables:

example attributes feeding -layer

[image: example attributes feeding -layer]

example attributes bear_buffer -layer

[image: example attributes bear_buffer -layer]

In the end, the result should be like on the following picture, so that I can import the table easily into Excel (because this doesn't work with the 7 millions features of the intersect-ouput) and doing my analyses.

example output-table (AAA, BBB, ... just represent other attributes), "bear_buffer"-features will be repeated for every "feeding"-features joined to the table
[image: example output-table (AAA, BBB, ... just represent other attributes), "bear_buffer"-features will be repeated for every "feeding"-features joined to the table]

How can I do this?

Have tried a lot of opportunities, nothing helped me to achieve the perfect result. If Excel could handle with 7 million features (rows) it would be easy with pivot table, but in this cases it's a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just divided the bears_buffer -layer into 4 smaller datasets, ran the intersect tool and loaded the output into excel. Then used the pivot table, worked very fine, but a more simple way would be better. The rest of the data needed, I joined by the spatial join tool.